# Deserialise an xml representation of a string and primitive type - ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, asp.net-web-api

I am currently implementing a web service with the ASP.net Web API and one of my methods returns a string.  The problem is it returns the string like this:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization">Some Resource</string>
```

This kind of response is what I want, but I don't know how to deserialise it in my web service client.

How would you deserialise any xml representing a string or any primitive datatype?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ReadAsAsync from the System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll.  Say 
'uri' will get me this data:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
  Some Resource
</string>
```

Then you can use ReadAsAsync to get the string in the XML:

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var resp = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;
        string value = resp.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>().Result;
```

(I'm calling .Result directly to demonstrate the use of ReadAsAsync<> here...)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Convert the raw data into a Stream
string rawData = "<string xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\">Some Resource</string>";
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rawData)); 

// User DataContractSerializer to deserialize it
DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(string));
string data = (string)serializer.ReadObject(stream);

Console.WriteLine(data);
```